# Multiplicative BIASES in Log-Log regression

Tags: regression, references, regression-coefficients, bias, elasticity

When we try to estimate elasticities by regression, we usually estimate the following regression model:

$$ln(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 ln(x_1) + \dots + \epsilon$$

When we expect to have **endogenous variables**, we would thought of our parameters as:

$$\beta_i = \beta_i^* + BIAS(\beta_i)$$

However, certain results may look like as if the bias was **multiplicative instead of additive** such as:

$$\beta_i = \beta_i^* \cdot BIAS(\beta_i)$$

This leads to self-reinforcing if the $BIAS(\cdot)$ is positive. When we expect the effect to be positive, it shows to be even more positive, and vice versa for expected negative effects, with the sign always being correct.

### The question:

- Does the log-log regression form frequently lead to multiplicative biases?
- If so, is there a literature on this topic?